# Find with multiple condition like or

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB but am getting a hang of it, but... I can't seem to figure out how to do this:

I have a user which is a part of multiple groups. These groups posts news on there walls. Now I am trying to find all news from this users groups and then sort them after the newest ones.

Here is how I am trying to do this so far:

```
dataList.find({ "groupId": [groupIds], "tstamp": { $gt: tstamp }}).limit( 5 );
```

I think that the groupIds should be an json object like this:

```
{"12345", "54321"}
```

but that doesn't work :-/

Hope somebody can help me and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mongoDB `$in` clause for this task:

```
dataList.find({ "groupId": {$in : groupIds}, "tstamp": { $gt: tstamp }}).limit( 5 );
```

`groupIds` must be an array of `id`s.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/